# Regex to express an operation in latex

Tags: regex, matlab, latex, arithmetic-expressions

- Hello, i want to formulate a regex expression outputted by matlab instruction `solve` to express an arithmetic operation in latex symboles as the example which follows:

`(a+b^(c-d))/b` -> `\frac{(a+b^{(c-d)})}{b}`

allowed input patterns:

> /+-*^\w\s()

allowed output patterns:

> +-*^\w\s(){}

- about division, [This](https://regex101.com/r/mG4vG1/1) is what i have tried so far

The caught expressions are stored in variables{division,numerator,denominator}

- about exponentiation, I v tried [This](https://regex101.com/r/wQ0tP4/1)

Unfortunately,I found my self faced to couple of problems, one of them, is that my matlab version doesnt accept this kind of recursive regex. but I could implement it as iterative function:

```
a='^(dfdf ^(sdf) )';b=' ';while(~strcmp(a,b))b=a;a=regexprep(a, '\^\((?<betweenbrackets>.*)\)', '\^{$<betweenbrackets>}');end
```

Could you advice me anyway else to do it for both exponentiation and division ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox, you can just say

```
latex(sym('(a+b^(c-d))/b'))
```

```
ans =

\frac{a + b^{c - d}}{b}
```